# Последовательность Фибоначчи в с++

Tags: c++, числа-фибоначчи

Требуется записать последовательность Фибоначчи данная шаблоном
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется напечатать первых десять выражений. 
Может кто помочь?

Comment: Отсутствие попыток решения вопроса, не является оправданием. Голосую за закрытие и -1

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Это настолько легко гуглится, что вам должно быть стыдно.

```
constexpr int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Как вывести значения в цикле, я надеюсь, вы найдете сами.

Comment: Преподносить ответ на блюде на кануне сессии ленивым студентам, которые даже не пытаются гуглить...

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да ладно, это же самое неэффективное решение :) Пусть он попробует посчитать что-то типа `fibonacci(50)` :) Ощущение, что это было сделано именно для того, чтоб препод мог поизгаляться..

Comment: @Harry Вы знаете, некоторые студенты готовы хоть сутки ответа ждать, лишь бы в конце поставили заветный зачет :) Ну а вообще вы правы, решение не самое умное.

Comment: Не удивляйтесь моему вопросу. Я учусь в Польше на первом курсе, и преподавание тут слабое. Теоретический материал абсолютно не соответствует тому, что требуют на заданиях.

Comment: @Minorus, а причем здесь "преподавание" и гугл? В данном задании от вас не требуют чего-то космического, если вы не можете самостоятельно изучить азы языка... ну это довольно странно, как вы после университета то работать будете? Или все задачи по работе тоже сюда будут поститься? :)